# Missing required attribute: dependency groupId in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I have created one flutter package locally inside flutter module and it was working fine as expected  but while integrating with another android app getting the below error,

```
Missing required attribute: dependency groupId
```

And integrated the .aar in the below way,

```
Consuming the Module
  1. Open <host>/app/build.gradle
  2. Ensure you have the repositories configured, otherwise add them:

      String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"
      repositories {
        maven {
            url '/home/reddy/AndroidStudioProjects/sdkmodule/build/host/outputs/repo'
        }
        maven {
            url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
        }
      }

  3. Make the host app depend on the Flutter module:

    dependencies {
      debugImplementation 'com.npst.sdkmodule:flutter:1.0:debug'
      profileImplementation 'com.npst.sdkmodule:flutter:1.0:profile'
      releaseImplementation 'com.npst.sdkmodule:flutter:1.0:release'
    }


  4. Add the `profile` build type:

    android {
      buildTypes {
        profile {
          initWith debug
        }
      }
    }
```

Can any one provide the cause of the issue?